# Usage of prune not working in find command

Tags: find

I am trying to use prune as:

```
find /opt/app/bss/sieb/fs_clone1/userpref -name "*" -type f -mtime -7 -prune
```

This is still searching sub-directories.

Answer (score 3):

It's still searching sub-directories because you're not `-prun`ing any.

To `-prune` a `find` tree you must first match it.

```sh
find / -type d ! -path / -prune -print
```

---

```
/boot
/home
/mnt
/opt
/esp
/dev
/proc
/root
/run
/srv
/sys
/tmp
/usr
/var
/etc
```

I had to use `-path /` because otherwise the first directory found would have been `/` the root and *it* would be `-prune`'d then `-print`ed.

But as you can see, it is the *matched* files that are `-prune`d and nothing else. So if you *match* `-type f` you won't `-prune` any trees at all - regular files have no subdirectories.

You probably want something like:

```
find /opt/app/bss/sieb/fs_clone1/userpref \
     -path \*path/to/ignore -prune -o     \
   ! -type d -mtime -7
```

This is very different than your statement. In the first place `-path path/to/ignore` doesn't work. It has to match a *whole* path, and your start tree starts with `/` but `path/to/ignore` doesn't at all. So I put `*` globstar in, but better - and probably more succinct could be:

```
cd /opt/app/bss/sieb/fs_clone1/userpref &&
find . -path ./path/to/ignore -prune -o  \
     ! -type d -mtime 7
```

...which would make your output a lot less messy. Either way, though, the all paths matched by the `-path` pattern will be `-prune`'d then *not* printed because we `-o` away to another statement and it is only the last expression of the entire `find` script that is autoprinted.

The last part is also different, though. I dropped `-name '*'` because all names match `'*'` and so you might as well just not filter on that. And the `! -type d` is what I've found a lot of people often mean when they say `-type f`. The former matches any file type which is not a directory - to include fifos and sockets and the rest of the weird ones. The latter matches only regular files. It maybe you really do want the latter - but I just thought I'd mention it.

Anyway, when all is said and done the `*path/to/ignore` is matched, pruned, and not printed, then, of everything else, files which are not type directory and which were modified 7 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /opt/app/bss/sieb/fs_clone1/userpref -type f -mtime -7 -path path/to/ignore -prune -o -print
```

But I think what you need is `-depth`.

Note that `−maxdepth 0` means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments. `−mindepth 1` means process all files except the command line arguments.